# How would I create this report in reporting services for the report viewer control?

Tags: c#, .net, reporting-services, reportviewer

I have this dataset created in Visual Studio 2008 in my project. I have already filled each table with the data that I need. There will be multiple tickets and each child table will have either 0 or more items relating to the ticket table. There are no relationships established as part of the dataset (yet). I also have this report created that handles a single ticket just fine. If possible I would like to expand this to handle multiple tickets.

The dataset is passed in to the report and the from the report viewer control is on has a binding source set up for each table in the dataset.

[image]
  [image]

I need the report to print out each ticket with child data on a single page (or two as needed). Then for the next ticket start a new page.

I have not yet been able to come up with a grouping scheme for the information that will work. I have gotten all of the tables to show up but I haven't been able to access the child information without the FIRST aggregate, which doesn't help because each ticket gets the same 1 record for each section printed.

Any suggestions? I know that there is more info potentially needed so please ask questions as needed and I will update this post with more info and/or comments.

Edit: We ended up turning the child data tables into sub-reports. We then passed the ticket number into the sub-report as a parameter and filtered the child data tables appropriately. Other than some minor formatting issues we had to work though this solved what we needed to do. Each ticket was put in a list and the sub-reports run for each ticket.

- Start Report
- Ticket 1
- -- Subreport with notes, history, & responses.
- Ticket 2
- -- Subreport with notes, history, & responses.
- etc
- End Report

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like you need put all of your information/controls into a single table control. Then format the table control for the look that you want.

Comment: This isn't quite what we ended up doing. I realized I never accepted the answer. We have recently come back and revisited this and I will update the question with the route we took.